# PHP numeric data validation

Tags: php

I need to add data validation to the following PHP code so that the user is only allowed to enter a number in the price and percent field, anything else will give them a warning. I tried different if statements but haven't had any luck. any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

$product_description = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_description');
$list_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'list_price');

$discout_percent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'discount_pecenr');

$discount = $list_price*$discout_percent*.10;
$discount_price = $list_price - $discount;

$list_price_f = "$".number_format($list_price, 2);
$discountt_prcent_f= $discout_percent."%";
$discount_f = "$".number_format($discount,2);
$discount_price_f = "$".number_format($discount_price,2);
if(!empty($_POST['list_price'])){
$list_price = $_POST['list_price'];
if(!is_numeric($list_price)){
  $list_price = NULL; echo "Postcode must be numeric.<br/>";
}
}
else{
$list_price = NULL; echo "You must enter a postcode.<br/>";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Discount Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Product Discount Calculator</h1>

    <label>Product Description:</label>
    <span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product_description); ?></span><br>

    <label>List Price:</label>
    <span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($list_price_f); ?></span><br>

    <label>Standard Discount:</label>
    <span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($discount_percent_f); ?></span><br>

    <label>Discount Amount:</label>
    <span><?php echo $discount_f; ?></span><br>

    <label>Discount Price:</label>
    <span><?php echo discount_price_f; ?></span><br>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML I'm using for this is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Discount Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Product Discount Calculator</h1>
    <form action="display_discount.php" method="POST">

        <div id="data">
            <label>Product Description:</label>
            <input type="text" name="product_description"><br>

            <label>List Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="list_price"><br>

            <label>Discount Percent:</label>
            <input type="text" name="discount_percent"><span>%</span><br>
        </div>

        <div id="buttons">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Discount"><br>
        </div>

    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: There's a [number input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp) as well. Any specific reason you're not using that?

Comment: the idea is to show a message to the user saying the information entered is invalid.

Comment: The number input should validate automatically. What have you tried so far to validate manually?

Comment: this is an if statement I used and it made no change.
if(!empty($_POST['list_price'])){
    $list_price = $_POST['list_price'];
    if(!is_numeric($list_price)){
      $list_price = NULL; echo "Postcode must be numeric.<br/>";
    }
  }
  else{
    $list_price = NULL; echo "You must enter a postcode.<br/>";
  }

Comment: Please edit the question to add code, it's difficult to read in the comments. Insert it where you were using it, maybe you didn't use it properly.

Comment: I just made your suggested edits. it should be showing properly now.

Comment: You should name your submit button and wrap your entire logic in an `if` condition checking if its name is set. If it is, that means the form was submitted and you can use the values.

Comment: For things like that, I use Javascript.  This way it validates the values even before the submit button is pressed.  No need to send it server side.  Research Javascript, form fields validation.